# How to transfer files in order (first come first serve) using apache camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel

In my code there are two types of files with extension .csv or .psv and .tigger files. .csv files have more size than .trigger files, so .trigger files are getting transfer in prior to .csv files.

How to make sure that once .csv files are transferred only .trigger files should be transferred.

Am using same single route to transfer both the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sortBy-option of the camel file component. See http://camel.apache.org/file2.html for more information.

Comment: In my case , there are two types of files csv and its corresponding trigger files. 

I should first transfer csv files, once csv files gets transferred only i should get acknowledgement and i should be able to  transfer its corresponding trigger file of same date. 


Thanks in prior

Comment: So there is a file called 123.csv and a file called 123.trigger? Maybe you could use 2 sortBy's. One for the filename without extension and the second one with the fileExtension?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to implement camel's `org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter` and write your filter logic in `accept` method. Logic should pick all the csv files first and then the trigger files. Use filter option of file component, from end point will be like:

```
from("file://inbox?filter=myFilter")
```

Comment: It has only one method to be overridden "accept" method. that method is used to filter what files should be transferred like files before 7 days.